# Can I install an RPM requiring special arguments as part of Kickstart?

Tags: rpm, rhel7

I have a vendor-provided RPM that normally asks the user to accept an EULA agreement as part of package installation. Basically the preinstall script (as displayed by rpm -qa --scripts) looks like this:

```
rm -f /tmp/mypackage_EULA.txt
echo "Lots and lots of lines of EULA stuff" >> /tmp/mypackage_EULA.txt
echo "Press 'q' to continue" >> /tmp/mypackage_EULA.txt
less -X /tmp/mypackage_EULA.txt

echo "By installing this package you are agreeing to the license, &c."
echo "Press 'a' to agree"

ans=""

while [ "$ans" == "" ]
do
    read -n 1 ans
done

if [ "$ans" != "a" ]; then
    echo ""
    echo "aborting ..."
    exit 1
else
    echo ""
    echo "installing  ..."
fi
```

The vendor's notes suggest using --noscripts if you don't want to have to manually accept the EULA.

However, what I'd like to do is to install it as part of Kickstart, either by adding it to the %packages list or having it installed automatically as a prereq for other packages I'm installing.

- Is there any way to specify a command or configuration option (e.g. --noscripts or --nodeps) for a specific package in the Kickstart %packages list?
- If not, what workarounds should I use to install a not-quite-standard RPM like this?

Comment: What are they using to display the EULA and request the input?

Comment: @EtanReisner It looks a lot like less but I'm not exactly sure. What's the easiest way to dissect the RPM and figure it out?

Comment: `rpm -qp --scripts <package>` will list out the scriptlets in the package.

Comment: @EtanReisner Looks like it's a simple sh script that calls less. I added a stubbed-out version to the question text.

Comment: I can think of a few things that might work to work around that stupidity but I'd have to try them to be sure. Can you test what happens if you run `declare -rx ans=a; yum install <package>`? Does it wait for you to supply input or does it just install silently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **strongly** dislike vendors who do things like that which break automated installation of their RPMs. (`--noscripts` is **not** safe to use on arbitrary packages and can **greatly** break things if used incorrectly.)

I don't believe (though I haven't specifically looked) that you can set up options like that for packages listed in the `%packages` section of a kickstart script.

There are two things I think you can do to work around this problem.

You can manually install just that RPM in a `%post` script and thus pass `--noscripts` as instructed (though be aware that `CentOS 7`'s version of `yum` is likely to "yell" at you a bit for making changes to the rpmdb outside of its control though it should recover just fine).

Alternatively you could see if you can feed whatever they are using to request that information what it wants from standard input and do something like

```
echo a | yum install <package>
```

Comment: If you do it in post you can't install anything that depends on it in %packages, though, right? :(

Comment: Unfortunately this does mean that, yes. You could repackage the RPMs yourself without that horrible `%pre` scriptlet (I'm assuming) and use that if you really wanted to.

Comment: Thanks, Etan! In the end, I ended up repackaging it with rpm2cpio, which allowed me to trim down the package to just the needed libs anyway. (I've put in an edit to merge your comment into the answer body itself.)